# Are questions regarding how to spend rare resources on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

A game I am playing has a rather rare resource, which I am uncertain how to spend effectively. I would like to ask a question on what the best way to spend said resource would be, but I'm worried it would be considered too subjective or too opinion-based.

What can I do to make the question acceptable?

Comment: I think in this case, it almost depends on the game itself. In certain games there is an objectively best way to spend your rare resources. In others, there is no clear best way (maybe an MMO). Which game are you wanting to ask about?

Comment: @nightsurfer I wanted to ask about Fate/Grand Order - specifically about rare mana prisms. They are, as the name implies, pretty rare, and the opinions I have found online vary wildly, ranging from "Trial quests are so good!" to "Never ever spend money on Trial Quests!". Hence why I was worried it could be considered too opinion-based. Ideally, an answer would be backed up with something more tangible than "because I think so".

Comment: Personally I would say it's probably fine, but let's wait for some more answers :)

Answer (score 9):

Usually, *the best way* questions often get viewed as being too opinionated/subjective like you said.  But, if you look at our ["avoid asking" help page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
>
> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - tend to have long, not short, answers
> - have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
> - are more than just mindless social fun

Personally, I would consider your particular question as more of a strategical question on how to best use this rare resource, and strategical questions [are on topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> - Gameplay strategies and tactics

One other thing you may want to consider is changing your question to be more definitive.  Maybe instead of asking "the best" thing to spend the resource on, you could ask what are all the things you *can* you spend it on.  This may indirectly answer your original question, while also being less opinionated.

Comment: And avoid using the word "best".  Even if there's an objective way of deciding which usage gets the highest return on investment, people will see that word and reflexively vote to close as subjective.